# C++ override quotes

Tags: string, c++11, overriding, operators

Ok, so I'm using C++ to make a library that'd help me to print lines into a console.

So, I want to override " "(quote operators) to create an `std::string` instead of the string literal, to make it easier for me to append other data types to that string I want to output.

I've seen this done before in the `wxWidgets` with their `wxString`, but I have no idea how I can do that myself.

Is that possible and how would I go about doing it?

I've already tried using this code, but with no luck:

```
class PString{
    std::string operator""(const char* text, std::size_t len) {
        return std::string(text, len);
    }
};
```

I get this error:

```
error: expected suffix identifier
 std::string operator""(const char* text, std::size_t len) {
                     ^~
```

which, I'd assume, want me to add a suffix after the "", but I don't want that. I want to only use ""(quotes).

Thanks!

Comment: There is [no `""` operator and you cannot overload it](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators). There are [user defined literals](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/user_literal) but they require a suffix.

Comment: Thanks! What is it if it isn't operator?

Comment: The `""` are part of [string literals](http://eel.is/c++draft/lex.string).

Comment: that makes sense now... Thanks :D

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `""` without defining a suffix. `""` is a `const char*` by itself either with a prefix (like `L""`, `u""`, `U""`, `u8""`, `R"()"`) or followed by suffixes like (`""s`, `""sv`, `...`) which can be overloaded.

Answer (score 0):

The way that wxString works is set and implicit constructor `wxString::wxString(const char*);` so that when you pass `"some string"` into a function it is essentially the same as `wxString("some string")`.

Overriding `operator ""X` yields string literals as the other answer.